# Is there a name for the convergent/divergent status of a series, sequence, or integral? A name for its "behavior" as far as those ideas are concerned?

Tags: calculus, terminology, convention

My professor refers to it as "con-dive behavior", but I'm almost certain that that's not an actual term. For example, he might ask: "what is the condive behavior of the harmonic series?", to which we would answer "divergent".

Is there a legitimate word/terminology that has the same usage as "condive behavior" in that example?

Comment: I think it would be preferable to simply ask "Does the series converge?".

Answer (score 1):

The professor, perhaps, is using short-term "condive behaviour" to mean "convergence-divergence behaviour". 
But this is not a world-wide accepted acronym.

Another technical term you might like to use is: "limiting behaviour" of the series (as $n\to\infty$).